# Scheduler error on server but not on local host in Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, runtime-error, shared-hosting

I am testing scheduler and for this, I tested the code on Local machine and it works perfectly, but on live serve, I am facing below error for `foreach loop`

```php
[2019-11-27 23:00:01] local.ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at /demon/x/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:261)
[stacktrace]
#0 /demon/x/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(261): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/demon/x...', 261, Array)
#1 /demon/x/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(983): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput->getFirstArgument()
#2 /demon/x/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(81): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->getCommandName(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput))
#3 /demon/x/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /demon/x/public_html/artisan(36): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
"}
```

the function I am trying to call is as below and is in helper function:

```php
   function sendNotificationToScheduleMessages() {
        // from current time 
        $from  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now'));
        // to the time max
        $to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 minutes', strtotime('now')));

        //get all pending notification between from and to date timestamp
        $notification = ScheduleMessage::whereBetween('trigger_at', [$from, $to])->whereStatusId(4)->get();
        if(count($notification) > 0){
            Log::info('Data fetched for notification #record - '.$notification->id);
        } else {
            Log::info('No Notification found form ('.$from.') - to ('.$to.')');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in the past.  You haven't shown some of your scheduler info, but I was able to solve this via fixing my `cron` instruction.  So, on your live server, make sure you actually have added Laravel's scheduler to `cron`.

Something like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php register_argc_argv=1 artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This worked for me, but you may need to play around in this space to match the functionality between your dev machine and the live host.

HTH

Comment: `register_argc_argv=1` is on in my case so not related to that and i have tried this before posting.